# JavaFX - Dispose of window

Tags: java, javafx, dispose

I've got a window in JavaFX that I need to 'clean' I.E: Reset the values of all of the fields and set it back to how it was when it was initialised. I figured I could do something like `window.dispose()`, but it turns out nothing like that appears to exist.

This seems like a massive oversight in the window engine as I'm going to be opening multiple windows that I don't want to persist. If I do `stage.close()` it just hides the window without releasing the memory, potentially leading to memory leaks.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `stage.close()` leads to memory leaks? This only happens (like with any other Java object) when the object you are dereferencing has other strong references which you somehow are keeping alive.

Comment: Well, I've `.close()`d and resurrected windows and they retain the data applied to them, so I figure if I loop creating new and `.close()`ing them, eventually I'd run out of memory

Comment: Indeed close() is equivalent to calling hide(), it does not destroy the Stage, that's why you keep all the information inside. See the [doc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#close()) (same story for JavaFX 8).

With JavaFX, the resources are only released when the life-cycle of the Application ends ([see doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html)).

What I did in one of my application is Binding my fields with Properties. This way I'm able to control all the values directly from the properties (bidirectional binding).

Comment: As @eckig says, if you call `stage.close()` (or `stage.hide()`) *and do not retain references to the `stage`*, then the stage will be garbage collected and any resources associated with it will be released. If you call `close()` "and then resurrect it", you obviously still have a reference to it (how else did you "resurrect" it?), so you have prevented it from being garbage collected.

Comment: @VincentG neither of the links you provide say that resources associated with windows are retained until the application exits.

Comment: Ok, so I have to lose the strong reference to it? I'm storing a reference to each Stage in a HashMap, so would just setting the value to null remove the reference?

Comment: Yes, just remove it from your `Map` (assuming you are not retaining references elsewhere).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `close()`, (or, equivalently, `hide()`) on a window, the FX toolkit will release any references it holds to that window. Consequently, as long as you do not retain references to the window, once `close()` has been called it will be eligible for garbage collection. It behaves like any other Java object with respect to garbage collection - once garbage collected, resources associated with the window are released.

Here's a demo that opens a new window every second, closing the previous window when it does so. The window displays an image in a label, so it consumes a reasonable chunk of memory. The primary stage displays memory statistics (also updating every second). This behaves exactly as you would expect, with the memory gradually increasing until the garbage collector kicks in, at which point the memory usage drops back. (On my system, it cycles between ~7MB and ~65MB; your mileage may vary depending on OS, JDK version, and system resources.) You can insert a call to `System.gc();` at the end of the `onSucceeded` handler (for demo purposes only; I do not recommend doing this in real code) if you want to see more clearly that garbage collection releases all the resources.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ConstantlyOpenWindows extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ScheduledService<?> service = periodicallyShowNewWindow();

        Pane root = createMemoryMonitor();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 600));

        primaryStage.show();

        service.start();

    }


    private ScheduledService<Integer> periodicallyShowNewWindow() {

        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        double maxX = screen.getBounds().getMaxX();

        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
        ObjectProperty<Stage> visibleStage = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        ScheduledService<Integer> service = new ScheduledService<Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected Task<Integer> createTask() {
                Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
                    @Override 
                    public Integer call() {
                        return count.incrementAndGet();
                    }
                };
                return task ;
            }
        };

        service.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
            Stage lastStage = visibleStage.get();
            Stage stage = createWindowWithImage(service.getValue());
            visibleStage.set(stage);
            stage.setX(maxX - 480);
            stage.show();
            if (lastStage != null) {
                lastStage.close();
            }
//            System.gc();
        });

        service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(1));
        return service;
    }


    private Stage createWindowWithImage(int count) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        ImageView image = createImage();
        Label label = new Label("Window "+count);
        label.setGraphic(image);
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.BOTTOM);
        stage.setScene( new Scene(new StackPane(label), 480, 500) );
        return stage;
    }

    private ImageView createImage() {
        WritableImage img = new WritableImage(400, 400);
        Random rng = new Random();
        int x = rng.nextInt(40);
        int y = rng.nextInt(40);
        PixelWriter pw = img.getPixelWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 400 ; j++) {
                if (i >= x*10 && i < (x+1)*10 && j >= y*10 && j < (y+1) * 10) {
                    pw.setColor(i, j, Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE);
                } else {
                    pw.setColor(i, j, Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);
                }
            }
        }
        return new ImageView(img);
    }

    private Pane createMemoryMonitor() {
        LongProperty totalMemory = new SimpleLongProperty(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
        LongProperty freeMemory = new SimpleLongProperty(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        LongProperty maxMemory = new SimpleLongProperty(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        NumberBinding usedMemory = totalMemory.subtract(freeMemory);

        Label usedMemoryLabel = new Label();
        usedMemoryLabel.textProperty().bind(usedMemory.asString("Used memory: %,d"));
        Label freeMemoryLabel = new Label();
        freeMemoryLabel.textProperty().bind(freeMemory.asString("Free memory: %,d"));
        Label totalMemoryLabel = new Label();
        totalMemoryLabel.textProperty().bind(totalMemory.asString("Total memory: %,d"));
        Label maxMemoryLabel = new Label();
        maxMemoryLabel.textProperty().bind(maxMemory.asString("Max memory: %,d"));

        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        series.setName("Used memory");

        AtomicInteger time = new AtomicInteger();

        Timeline updateMemory = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> {
            totalMemory.set(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
            freeMemory.set(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            maxMemory.set(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
            series.getData().add(new Data<>(time.incrementAndGet(), usedMemory.getValue()));
            if (series.getData().size() > 100) {
                series.getData().subList(0, series.getData().size() - 100).clear();
            }    
        }));
        updateMemory.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        updateMemory.play();

        VBox labels = new VBox(usedMemoryLabel, freeMemoryLabel, totalMemoryLabel, maxMemoryLabel);
        labels.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel("Time");
        xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel("Memory");
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        chart.setAnimated(false);
        chart.getData().add(series);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(chart, labels, null, null, null);

        return root;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I would run your demo, if `javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService` actually existed in my installation

Comment: If you are still using JDK7/JavaFX2 you can just create a single `Task` and open/close the windows in a `Platform.runLater(...)`, `Thread.sleep(...)`ing in between each one. Or use a `Timeline` as I do in the "memory monitor". Obviously you also need to change all the lambda expressions to inner classes. Is there a reason you have to use the old version?

Comment: I use Mac, so I figure I either couldn't use Java 8 or something important didn't run with it, so I didn't install it.

Comment: Java 8 has been out in GA release for close to a year now. I use Java 8 u25 for "production" code on my Mac, as well as early access releases of both Java 8u40 and Java 9. All work fine.